# Jquery Bootstrap 4 password strength meter

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to replicate the strength meter like the following using bootstrap Jquery and CSS only. As in the given example is done using angular JS. I'm an absolute beginner to jQuery hence seeking assistance.

Original Link
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vxjef11j/208/)

My JSFiddle
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2b4zk57j/)

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>

        <div class="sign__forms__password__strength">
            <div class="strength__meter__fill">

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Below is an example of password strength meter u can refer this code.**

**HTML PAGE**

```js
$.strength = function(element, password) {
  var desc = [{
    'width': '0px'
  }, {
    'width': '20%'
  }, {
    'width': '40%'
  }, {
    'width': '60%'
  }, {
    'width': '80%'
  }, {
    'width': '100%'
  }];
  var descClass = ['', 'progress-bar-danger', 'progress-bar-danger', 'progress-bar-warning', 'progress-bar-success', 'progress-bar-success'];
  var score = 0;

  if (password.length > 6) {
    score++;
  }

  if ((password.match(/[a-z]/)) && (password.match(/[A-Z]/))) {
    score++;
  }

  if (password.match(/\d+/)) {
    score++;
  }

  if (password.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/)) {
    score++;
  }

  if (password.length > 10) {
    score++;
  }

  element.removeClass(descClass[score - 1]).addClass(descClass[score]).css(desc[score]);
};

$(function() {
  $("#pwd").keyup(function() {
    $.strength($("#progress-bar"), $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
}

*:focus {
  outline-style: none;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#progress {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.6em;
}

#progress-bar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 500ms linear;
}

.progress-bar-danger {
  background: #d00;
}

.progress-bar-warning {
  background: #f50;
}

.progress-bar-success {
  background: #080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="progress">
      <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we put another class name in your password input tag named "pwsd" and add another division for the result like your original link right after the input tag for password that we should store the result, assuming the class named "the_result"

```
 $('.pswd').on('keyup', function(e){
     var count = e.target.value.length;
    if(parseFloat(count) >= 7){
       $('.the_result').html('7+')
    }
    else{
     $('.the_result').html(parseFloat(count))
    }
 })
```